Selecting the screen with --auto-select-desktop-capture-source= in edgewebview2
I am doing the above flag on edgewebview2
std::wstring args;

args.append(L" --ignore-certificate-errors");
args.append(L" --hide-scrollbars");
args.append(L" --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");
args.append(L" --auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Screen 1");
args.append(L" --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");

auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(args.c_str());

HRESULT res = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
    nullptr, userDataFolder, options.Get(),
    new webview2_com_handler(wnd, cb,
                             [&](ICoreWebView2Controller *controller) {
                               m_controller = controller;
                               m_controller->get_CoreWebView2(&m_webview);
                               m_webview->AddRef();

                               flag.clear();
                             }));

in the dual display case, how to select screen 2,
I tried "Screen 2" but it seems to only reading Screen, so it always grabs screen 1, Any help is appreciated.

Please make sure you have used the correct name in place of "Screen 2", which is the "window name as shown in the desktop capture window picker". Also, try including the "name" inside the quotation marks.

Didn't help, it is always grabbing screen 1 in both cases, with quotation marks, the flag is not even getting set. also, why with --auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Screen 1, edgewebview2 doesn't share audio, with chrome it does and even with edge browser if I kill all webview processes and then launch edge browser with this switch it shares audio.

@ShashankShetty Have you also tried some windows? If you use the name of any window with a blank space in it, will the exact window be recognized? As to the audio problem, do you mean Microphone recording or webpage audio?

I'll try window names. For the audio issue, microphone I am able get through the flag "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", but i want the system audio or the webpage audio to be streamed.

@ShashankShetty Can you please provide a demo that supports capturing webpage/system audio? At least I'm not able to get it done.

Sorry for the delayed response, easiest way to reproduce is running a google meet call with that flag in both chrome(i killed all the chrome processes before running) and edgewebview2, then try to share the screen, which starts entire screen share with audio for chrome without the picker ui being shown. for edgewebview2 it does without audio.

were you able to reproduce the same?, using window names is not suitable for me, as it will not grab audio

using quotation marks solved screen grabbing issue, still not able to grab the audio, any leads?

@ShashankShetty I am able to reproduce this issue in WebView2. In Edge or Chrome, you are able to share audio only from the browser tabs. I think we are not allowed to share audio from WebView2 because it does not have the "tab".
